# Launching Multiple Docker Containers using Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I am trying to build an image and trying to launch multiple docker containers using ansible playbook. I am not able to understand how do i publish the ports. The below playbook gives me an error which is quite obvious that the port is already allocated but then how do i achieve this because from outside the containers there will only be one port right to acces all the containers?

Playbook -

```
- name: Manage Docker instances via Ansible
  hosts: shashank-VM
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Building an image from Dockerfile
      docker_image:
        build:
          path: .
          pull: yes
        name: web_new
        source: build

    - name: Creation of Docker Containers
      docker_container:
        name: my-app-{{ item }}
        image: web_new
        state: present
        ports:
         - "79:80"
      with_sequence: count=3

    - name: Starting Docker Containers
      docker_container:
        name: my-app-{{ item }}
        image: web_new
        state: started
      with_sequence: count=3
```

Error -

```
changed: [shashank-VM]

TASK [Creation of Docker Containers] *********************************************************************************************************
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=1)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=2)
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=3)

TASK [Starting Docker Containers] ************************************************************************************************************
changed: [shashank-VM] => (item=1)
failed: [shashank-VM] (item=2) => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "2", "msg": "Error starting container beb7f1d204f47862d16722f70b812df7193ddacf12d15350a9095cec2ebf4d85: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my-app-2 (880c06fe9e2efa75537e350734be1d46d0cc76e7acf70733d19ad38706dde5ab): Bind for 0.0.0.0:78 failed: port is already allocated\")"}
failed: [shashank-VM] (item=3) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "3", "msg": "Error starting container 048f2f3ea6fed5e094fdf59a4650b2b3f8164d804ee7dc8875e6e95bda1300d7: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my-app-3 (8247f75384b240cb9bf1ee66cc9f0404df5465e6c08903304f14bd813c218fa1): Bind for 0.0.0.0:78 failed: port is already allocated\")"}
```

NOTE : I have an application for which I am building an image and there will be multiple containers running for that image. How do i accessible my application from outside? How do i work on the ports?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How would you approach this problem, if Ansible weren't involved?  (Docker on its own doesn't provide a load balancer for you and you can't have multiple containers listening on the same host port.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I know.. I just thought there might be a way. I was doing this using Ansible so posted with Ansible. Do you think I should be looking at the reverer proxy may be apache or ngnix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is here:

```
> Bind for 0.0.0.0:78 failed: port is already allocated
```

Check what application/container blocks port `78`

- You can do it with `ss`:

```
sudo ss -plunt | grep :78
```

- Or with `lsof`:

```
lsof -i :78
```

- Or with `fuser`:

```
fuser -v -n tcp 78
```